# Any way to get a simple two column layout with only two elements?

Tags: css, css-float, multiple-columns

I mean like this:

```
definition | content......................
definition | content......................
definition | content......................
definition | content......................
```

With the definition column having fixed width, and the content column filling the remaining width.

I know how to make this with 3 container elements, but is it possible with only two?

For example using this markup:

```
<dl>

  <dt> definition </dt>
  <dd> content </dd>

  <dt> definition </dt>
  <dd> content </dd>

  <dt> definition </dt>
  <dd> content </dd>

  ..............
</dl>
```

I tried with:

```
dt{
  float:left;
  width: 200px;
}

dd{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

But if the definition column is higher than the content column, it messes up the whole layout :(

http://jsfiddle.net/LseGH/

Comment: This looks like it's tabular data, why not use a `table` tag?

Comment: No it's just the content of form, labels and input fields. I don't like tables and tables also take up 3 container elements for each row  :(

Comment: Can you explain that a little more? Are you trying to style a `form` with `labels` and `inputs` or a `dl`?

Comment: both. the dt contains labels and some other stuff, and the dd contains the input field, or group of input fields

Comment: This is an intersting article where the author handles the same issue: http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/

Comment: Instead of using `dt`/`dd`s, you should look into using `fieldsets`, simply because they are for grouping items inside `form`s. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to float both the `dt` and the `dd` elements, but clear the `dt` from floating next to the previous `dd`. I updated to add columns, 30% and 70% widths respectively, change as you'd like. Like this:

```
dt {
    clear: both; /* clears the previous floating dd element */
    float: left;
    width:30%;
}

dd {
    margin-left: 0; /* this is important to reset the margin & add the widths to 100% */
    float: left;
    width:70%;
}
```

[Example JS Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vrGbn/4/)

Comment: tried it but then `<dd>` doesn't fill the remaining horizontal space - http://jsfiddle.net/LseGH/2/

Comment: Updated for fixed column widths.

Comment: Well you had a _fixed_ width in your example, so if neither that nor percentages are what you want – then what else is it?

Comment: I meant fixed with for the first column, the 2nd column should take all available space left :)

Comment: It works with non-percentage widths too... I just don't have enough information of what you want and what specific widths you want. Like I said 30% and 70% are merely examples for the above working code. You can add whatever widths you want - technically 1,000px wide for each would work, you'd just alienate your users that don't have at least 2,000px wide monitors - so for the sake of an example, % works best.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `js` to make it work because without a shared parent, I don't know how to get the heights to play off each other. Basically, on page load, check the height of each `dt` and compare it to the following `dd`, then set both of their heights to the greater value. I changed some `css` to make it clearer to see.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/LseGH/4/)

Comment: Thanks but i`m not going to use javascript for this. But your answer tells me that it's not possible with CSS. Weird, because it's such a simple layout and CSS can't handle it even in 2014 :) So I guess I'm forced to use a container element for each row...